# Geocoding API is not reliable

Tags: rest, geocoding, bing, bing-maps

I have a problem with bing map geocoding API. The API is not reliable. The same query will not always return the same result.

This query
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/?key=myKey&o=xml&countryRegion=CA&postalCode=g0a4b0

will return no address

```
<Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
<Copyright>
Copyright © 2015 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.
</Copyright>
<BrandLogoUri>
http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png
</BrandLogoUri>
<StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
<StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription>
<AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode>
<ResourceSets>
<ResourceSet>
<EstimatedTotal>0</EstimatedTotal>
<Resources/>
</ResourceSet>
</ResourceSets>
</Response>
```

or an address

```
<Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
<Copyright>
Copyright © 2015 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.
</Copyright>
<BrandLogoUri>
http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png
</BrandLogoUri>
<StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
<StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription>
<AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode>
<ResourceSets>
<ResourceSet>
<EstimatedTotal>1</EstimatedTotal>
<Resources>
<Location>
<Name>G0A 4B0, QC</Name>
<Point>
<Latitude>46.679374694824219</Latitude>
<Longitude>-72.049674987792969</Longitude>
</Point>
<BoundingBox>
<SouthLatitude>46.675511977253542</SouthLatitude>
<WestLongitude>-72.0571812840852</WestLongitude>
<NorthLatitude>46.683237412394895</NorthLatitude>
<EastLongitude>-72.042168691500734</EastLongitude>
</BoundingBox>
<EntityType>Postcode1</EntityType>
<Address>
<AdminDistrict>QC</AdminDistrict>
<AdminDistrict2>Portneuf</AdminDistrict2>
<CountryRegion>Canada</CountryRegion>
<FormattedAddress>G0A 4B0, QC</FormattedAddress>
<Locality>Saint-Marc-des-Carrières</Locality>
<PostalCode>G0A 4B0</PostalCode>
</Address>
<Confidence>High</Confidence>
<MatchCode>Good</MatchCode>
<GeocodePoint>
<Latitude>46.679374694824219</Latitude>
<Longitude>-72.049674987792969</Longitude>
<CalculationMethod>Rooftop</CalculationMethod>
<UsageType>Display</UsageType>
</GeocodePoint>
</Location>
</Resources>
</ResourceSet>
</ResourceSets>
</Response>
```

Is there a way to make Bing geocoding API more reliable?

Is it because I use a basic key and they reject my query because the server is overload?

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the Bing API, it only says 'it does not work like I want', this should be asked to Microsoft ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is incorrect since it seems that you are not respecting the Terms of Use that you agreed with while creating the Basic Key.

Those type of key are limited in number of request for a given period, here is a precise article on the MSDN that explain those limits in details:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894107.aspx

And another regarding the status and the code:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701703.aspx

**Rate limitation and information**

Here is the interesting part to go further managing your error:

> Rate Limiting
>
> In the Bing Maps terms of use trial and basic keys are
> limited in the number of transactions they can generate within a
> period of time. Windows Store, Windows Phone, and WPF apps have a
> limit of 50,000 transactions in a 24 hour period. Public facing web
> sites and non-Windows mobile apps have a limit of 125,000 transactions
> a year. Rate limiting occurs when the frequency of requests made
> against the Bing Maps REST and/or SOAP services by an account exceeds
> these free terms of use. Rate limiting can also occur when the
> services are under a lot of load. This is done to ensure that the
> usage from trial and basic keys do no interrupt the services for those
> using an Enterprise keys. Enterprise keys are not rate limited and the
> only way to get around rate limiting is to upgrade to an Enterprise
> key. For more information contact see our Bing Maps Licensing Options
> page.
>
> When a request is rate limited, the response will return no
> results. This may be confusing at first as it looks like Bing Maps was
> unable to find results. To indicate that the request was rate limited
> a flag is added to the header of the response (X-MS-BM-WS-INFO) which
> is set to the value of 1 as documented the Status Codes and Error
> Handling page. To make for a better user experience, applications that
> use trial or basic keys should look for this flag in the header and
> handle requests which are rate limited. Something as simple as logging
> the fact that a request was rate limited in your application log could
> help when debugging reported issues.

Comment: So it's not reliable. I can't take for granted that the results will be the same for a query.

Comment: Does the rate limited query count in my annual query limit?

Comment: The rate limitation include all limitations (hourly/daily/yearly).
It is reliable as long as you're using in the appropriate and accepted limits.

Comment: Sometimes my first query of the day won't work. it's because they don't want to interrupt the service for the entreprise keys.

Comment: Then you should consider contact the support through the Microsoft Bing Maps Portal (where you generated the key) by email and explain with appropriate logs. Also if you have lots of request to do, you might consider using the Bing Maps Batch Geocode.

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of other geocoding providers out there. If your application has to be able to depend on a geocoding provider that is fast, scalable, and reliable you will probably end up paying for a premium service.

[GeoCoding providers for non-map use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635818/geocoding-providers-for-non-map-use)

Comment: Not really answering the issue in this case